# Jenkins : Working on local environment but when I configure project on client hosted jenkins it is not working

Tags: selenium, jenkins, ant

I created a Hybrid driven framework for Selenium using ANT & TestNG. After then I installed jenkins on my local system and executed my code from there and all was working fine.

After then, my client gave me access to their jenkins system as an Admin user. I configured the project and connected with Code Repo and all other stuff done.
Then when I ran the project from there then on console I can see my test results over there but on my system browser doesn't start.

Any reason why I can't my scripts running....

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The thing is by default jenkins runs your scripts on Jenkins server only.

So in order to run scripts on your system you need to set Slave Settings.

You can add Slave Node from  Manage Jenkins >> Manage Nodes >> New Node.

After setting up your node you can run your script using the option "Restrict where this project can be run".

Comment: Hello, I logged into jenkins as an admin user then  Manage Jenkins --> Manage Nodes --> New node.   It's showing Node name option & radio button for "Dumb slave".  Should I select radio button for "Dumb slave"

Comment: yes dumb slave(for new slave setting)  than do the needful setting , like what all environmental variables you want to set , Labels , Limit Executions an so on

Comment: Okay thanks!! I will do it.  Can we connect on skype where I can share the screen with you.. if in case any problem I face.  my skype id: rohitsharma0187

Comment: I'm happy to help in this forum.Let me know if you need any more help.Also don't forget to accept the answer if the post helped you.